# File Download Using SharePlum for Sharepoint

Tags: file, sharepoint, download

I am using SharePlum to work with Sharepoint files/folder operations. I am able to create a folder and uplaod files with Shareplum. But I am not able to download a file. The code runs without any problem. I am not sure where the file gets downloaded.

```
def download():
    auth_cookie = Office365(base_path, username=username, password=password).GetCookies()
    full_path = urllib.parse.urljoin(urllib.parse.urljoin(base_path, "sites/"), site_name)
    logging.info("URL: %s", full_path)
    site = Site(full_path, version=Version.v2016, authcookie=auth_cookie)
    folder = site.Folder(folder_name)
    logging.info("folder name: %s", folder_name)
    folder.get_file('file.txt')
    folder.check_out(download_file)
    logging.info("Downloaded")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample demo:

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version

authcookie = Office365('https://xxx.sharepoint.com', username='user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com', password='password').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lee/', version=Version.v2016,authcookie=authcookie)
folder = site.Folder('MyDoc2')

file=folder.get_file('testdata.xlsx')
with open("testdata.xlsx", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(file)
print('---')
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer @Lee_MSFT. It helped me.